# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Undertow

Tags: https, url-rewriting, undertow

How can one configure HTTP->HTTPS redirection in Undertow? I've looked through Undertow's codebase, there are some classes that seem to be relevant (e.g. RedirectHandler). Also, Undertow documentation ([Predicates Attributes and Handlers](http://undertow.io/documentation/core/predicates-attributes-handlers.html)) seems to target exactly this problem among others. But I'm not sure where to start.

Basically, what I'm looking for is some counterpart to Apache's mod_rewrite configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466786/how-to-force-https-on-wildfly-8-1-in-openshift) pointed in the right direction. Programmatically, one has to add a `SecurityConstraint` to `Builder` and set `ConfidentialPortManager`:

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment();
servletBuilder.addSecurityConstraint(new SecurityConstraint()
  .addWebResourceCollection(new WebResourceCollection()
    .addUrlPattern("/*"))
  .setTransportGuaranteeType(TransportGuaranteeType.CONFIDENTIAL)
  .setEmptyRoleSemantic(EmptyRoleSemantic.PERMIT))
  .setConfidentialPortManager(new ConfidentialPortManager() {
    @Override
    public int getConfidentialPort(HttpServerExchange exchange) {
      return 443;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a 301 permanent redirect instead of the default 302 redirect with this method?

Comment: @Thermometer - not sure, never tried redirects with `DeploymentInfo`.

Comment: If you anybody wants the full implementation then refer the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908727/7538821